# Merging SVN feature branch back after main branch removed

Tags: svn, merge

```
/trunk
/branches/Build4
/branches/Feature
/branches/Build5
```

I created a **Feature** branch off of **Build4**. I periodically merged the changes from **Build4** into my **Feature** branch to keep it up to date. Now **Build4** is complete. It was merged back to **trunk**, then a **Build5** branch was created from **trunk**.  Here's a diagram:

```
        Feature ----------------------->
               /   /  /             
     Build4 -----------X   Build5 ----->
           /           \         /
trunk ------------------------------------------->
```

I want to get the changes from my **Feature** branch into **Build5**. Once that is done, my **Feature** branch can be deleted.  In the diagram, I want this to happen:

```
        Feature ---------------------X
               /   /  /              \
     Build4 -----------X   Build5 ----->
           /           \         /
trunk ------------------------------------------->
```

I have attempted merging **Feature** into **Build5**, merging **Build5** into **Feature** to update it, and merging **Build5** into **Feature** for only the revisions after the last merge into **Feature** from **Build4**. In all these cases I get conflicts that are not true conflicts. By this I mean the file did not actually change in both places, but somehow the lineage of the file is not being traced as I thought so it shows up as a conflict.

What is the recommended method get my **Feature** branch changes into a new branch from which it was not created, where both have common lineage?

I am using SVN server and SVN command line client versions 1.7.4.

Comment: Was Build4 created from trunk?

Comment: I added a diagram to hopefully help illustrate your scenario.  Please review it and modify it if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: A+ for the ASCII art. Yes, Build4 was created from Trunk. Your diagrams are an accurate depiction of what I have and what I want to do.

Comment: I would definitely recommend trying this merge using a more recent version of the client; 1.9.3 is the most current version.  Many merge-related bugs and improvements have been made since 1.7.4, notably [automatic merge](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#auto-reintegrate).

Comment: I tried the merge using the 1.9.3 client but there was no change. The same files showed up as conflicted. I did figure out how to merge without unexpected conflicts but I am still not sure why this was required. I merged the Feature branch into the Build5 branch, but only the revisions on the Feature branch where actual changes were committed. In this way, my merge from Feature to Build5 specifically did not include the revisions for those update merges from Build4 into Feature. All of my conflicts were coming from those prior merges. It is not pretty but it merges exactly what I want.

Comment: I'm not completely sure this is a supported scenario, but I'd think at a minimum you'd need to merge _Build5_ to _Feature_ before you could integrate _Feature_ into _Build5_.